# What's the situation that the Ext.define has to set the uses property?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I had searched and read the [ExtJS Doc](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.Class-cfg-uses). It says:

```
Ext.define('Mother', {
    uses: ['Child'],
    giveBirth: function() {
        // This code might, or might not work:
        // return new Child();

        // Instead use Ext.create() to load the class at the spot if not loaded already:
        return Ext.create('Child'); // will find and load the Child.js file
    }
});
```

but i try:

```
Ext.define('Mother', {
    giveBirth: function() {
        return Ext.create('Child'); // will find and load the Child.js file, too
    }
});
```

What's the difference when I set the uses property?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's to avoid cyclic dependencies.

Consider the following example:

`src/Foo.js`

```
Ext.define('Test.Bar', {
    requires: 'Test.Foo'
}, function() {
    console.log('Loaded Bar');
});
```

`src/Bar.js`

```
Ext.define('Test.Foo', {
    requires: 'Test.Bar'
}, function() {
    console.log('Loaded Foo');
});
```

`app.js`

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true
    ,paths: {
        Test: 'src'
    }
});

Ext.require('Test.Foo');

Ext.onReady(function() {
    alert('Everything\'s loaded!');
});
```

The alert will never fires. If you tries that with a dev build (eg. `ext-all-dev.js`), the loader will tell you why:

```
> Uncaught Error: Deadlock detected while loading dependencies! 'Test.Foo' and 'Test.Bar' mutually require each other. Path: Test.Foo -> Test.Bar -> Test.Foo
```

Replaces the `requires` with `uses` in any of the two classes, and problem solved, alert shooting.

To address the last part of your question, you should avoid using `Ext.create` completely... In part for performance reasons, but especially because in dev mode, while the dynamic Loader is enabled, you won't notice missing `requires` if you use it. And that may cost you some time to find all the missing one when you'll try to compile your app... While this will cause a crash you can't miss:

```
new My.Class();
```

Answer (score 3):

The `Uses` property is a list of optional classes to load together with this class. These aren't necessarily loaded before this class is created, but are guaranteed to be available before `Ext.onReady` listeners are invoked.

[ExtJS Doc you cited](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.Class-cfg-uses)

`Uses` is saying those classes `['Child']` need to be defined before this class `'Mother'` is instantiated. The `onReady` function will defer to fire until the `requires` classes are defined but will fire if the `uses` classes aren't.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to declare dependencies, the recommended way is to put them in the `requires` property:

```
Ext.define('Foo', {
    requires: ['Bar'],

    getBar: function() {
        // Bar class is guaranteed to be loaded
        return new Bar();
    }
});
```

In fact `uses` has one and only one purpose: to break circular dependencies.

```
Ext.define('Foo', {
    requires: ['Bar'],
    ...
});

Ext.define('Bar', {
    // Can't use requires here, as this would create a deadlock
    // OTOH we should let the Loader know that Bar depends
    // on Foo, so that Foo would be loaded too, eventually
    uses: ['Foo'],
    ...
});
```

Technically speaking, `requires` will guarantee that the dependencies are loaded before the class that depends on them is created; `uses` will only guarantee that the dependencies will be loaded before the `onready` event is fired, i.e. when everything has been loaded.

TL;DR You shouldn't be using `uses` at all. Use `requires` instead.